# Nestjs wrapping external module in forRootAsync and inject instance

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-providers

I've been developing a wrapper module for `nestjs` based on a `nodejs` module. I created a static `forRoot` method in order to get the configuration. I created such a prodiver within the `forRoot` method:

```js
const MyProvider = {
  provide: PROVIDER_TOKEN,
  useValue: new MyClass(options),
};
```

I also export it, so in consumer module it's easy to inject it in order to access to all methods of nodejs module. Besides, I am able to wrap up all methods of that module into my service methods. So, the following code give me access to the main module's instance:

```js
constructor(@Inject(PROVIDER_TOKEN) private readonly myClass: MyClass) {}
```

Then I decided to create a `forRootAsync` method that can handle getting configuration with `useFactory`. Now this is my provider in `forRootAsync` method:

```js
const MyProvider= {
  provide: PROVIDER_TOKEN,
  useFactory: optionsAsync.useFactory,
  inject: optionsAsync.inject || []
};
```

But this time if I inject `PROVIDER_TOKEN` to the service, this is simply the configuration object (that I pass from the consumer module). So I guess I should create the instance within constructor. Maybe something like this:

```js
constructor(@Inject(PROVIDER_TOKEN) private readonly myClass) {
  if(!this.myClass typeof MyClass) {
    this.myClass = new MyClass(this.myClass);
  }
}
```

By this, I can't access the instance of the main module in the consumer modules by injecting `PROVIDER_TOKEN` token. The goal is to access all methods of that module without having to wrap all the methods up. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should handle this with two providers. In the first one, we pass the factory provider as following:

```js
{
  provide: HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS,
  useFactory: options.useFactory,
  inject: options.inject || [],
};
```

Then we create another provider which injects the first provider (which nestjs resolve the dependency at that point):

```js
{
  provide: AXIOS_INSTANCE_TOKEN,
  useFactory: (config: HttpModuleOptions) => Axios.create(config),
  inject: [HTTP_MODULE_OPTIONS],
},
```

Here is the [example](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/http/http.module.ts).